# How to stop service when removing widget from homescreen

Tags: android, service, widget

I have a problem with service. I'm trying to do a simple battery level widget but the problem is that I don't know how to stop service when the widget is removed from homescreen.

Here is my service class

public class batteryService extends Service{

```
AppWidgetManager widgetManager;
private RemoteViews remoteViews;
private ComponentName thisWidget;

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)*100;
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1); 
        float value = (float)level/scale;
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, String.valueOf(value));
        widgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

and here widget class

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{
    private AppWidgetManager widget_manager;
    private RemoteViews remoteViews;
    private ComponentName thisWidget;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        if(intent == null)
        {
            intent = new Intent(context, batteryService.class);
            context.startService(intent);
        }
        super.onEnabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        if(intent != null)
        {
            context.stopService(intent);
            intent = null;
        }       
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }


}
```

When I remove widget from screen the service is still a live. I was trying to change onDisable to onDeleted method but it didn't change anything.

Have you any tips for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate action in your manifest for the disabled event:

```
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
```

This would be alongside your existing `APPWIDGET_ENABLED` and perhaps the classic `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` actions, for the `<receiver>` element for your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Also, please consider not having your service run constantly, but rather updating the battery information once every few minutes using `AlarmManager`. The battery level simply does not change that often to make it necessary to attempt to keep a service in memory all of the time.

Comment: I have this declaration inside my manifest and it still doesn't work. I guess there is something wrong with my code I need to read a litte more about services working with widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `onDeleted(Context, int[])`